# Cannot upgrade Node.js version in Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure

My Azure app service is running Node.js version 0.10:

```
> node -v
D:\home\site\wwwroot
v0.10.28
```

I am trying to upgrade it to version 8.

There's an article here describing how to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps

First, I added the key in the Application Settings in Azure Portal:

[image: Node JS Version in Azure]

It didn't work, so I also changed packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "azure_cosmos_db_webservice",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect server.js"
  },
  "engines":{"node": "8.x"}, <-- This line added by me
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "documentdb": "^1.10.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

I've restarted the app service several times by stopping and starting it again.

However, `node -v` in the console in Azure Portal is still showing the version as 0.10.28.

What did I miss?

Comment: did you install v8.x of node?

Comment: @SatishPatel Install where? This is an Azure app service so I assume all versions of Node are already installed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out that `8.x` was not a correct syntax.

I've changed it to 8.1.4 both in packages.json and in the Application Settings, and it worked.

I found the list of supported versions here:

https://MYSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me figure out what version of Node was available on azure!

Comment: Thanks for the supported versions tip - that was a real help!